# Trying to compare a string to an array and return string, instead of a value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to write a function that looks at the string in a cell and depending on the first 2-3 letters write a string in the cell next to it.

For example:

> "LSH T1402A" should return "High-Level Safety"
>   "FI P1402A" should return "Flow Indicator"

(I know in the second case there are only 2 symbols, but in the array I would include the space in the string so that shouldn't give any problems)

At first I was thinking of using an IF function, but quickly abandoned the idea because it would become too lengthy.(many different strings/types of sensors)

Currently I've broken down my problem in 4 steps

1. Read String
2. Return first 3 symbols
3. Compare to array/matrix
4. Write string corresponding.

The first two parts I think I can solve by using `"=LEFT(TRIM([CEL]);3)` but I am stuck on how to compare it to an array. The `MATCH` function comes close but only returns a value for which position the cell is on I believe?

Does anyone have an idea how I should continue solving this problem? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your array was say in `G1:H10` then you could

- lookup your 3 character code in G1:G10 using `MATCH`
- return the corresponding value from H1:H10 using `INDEX`

*example*

```
=INDEX(H1:H10,MATCH(LEFT(A1,3),G1:G10,0))
```

*Function will return a #N/A if no match is found*

Comment: I ended up tweaking it a little bit "=INDEX(K$1:K$20;MATCH(LEFT(TRIM(B3);3);J$1:J$20;0))" But this was a perfect solution for my problem. Thank you